# Define alternative image path in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, cdn

Actually I have a css snipped like this:

```
.item1 {
    background-image: url("../img/myimage1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I will replace this background image with an CDN image url:

```
background-image: url("https://cdn.com/img/myimage1.jpg");
```

I would like to make sure that if there is a problem with the CDN provider that an image is loaded anyway. How can I now specify an alternative local image path in addition to the defined CDN url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using javascript. But using your provided CSS codes just add the second to your url something like this:

```
background-image: url("https://cdn.com/img/myimage1.jpg"), url("https://otherdomain/img/myimage1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

@JustAce answer would do the job.
but it can be done with JS way if your interested in:
HTML:

```
<test onerror="changeImg()" >sdf</test>
```

JS:

```
function changeImg(){
    $('.item1').css('backgroud-image','src(".....")')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the path from the Image from ur Devise in your CSS

Like:

```
.item1 {
    background-image: url("C:\Useer\Images\my_Image.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.item1 {
    background-image: url("../img/myimage1.jpg"), url("https://cdn.com/img/myimage1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: A good answer should provide an explanation rather than just a piece of code. Please, try to explain what led you to write this code and how it would help face the issue.